# Package glossaries causing warning

Tags: glossaries

I am using MiKTeX 2.9 with TeXnicCenter. In order to adjust the space between acronyms and remove alphabetical grouping I define a new glossary style `mylong`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[toc, nonumberlist,nopostdot]{glossaries}

\setlength{\glsdescwidth}{0.8\linewidth}

\newglossarystyle{mylong}{
\glossarystyle{long}
  \renewcommand*{\glossaryentryfield}[5]{%
    \glsentryitem{##1}\glstarget{##1}{##2} & ##3\glspostdescription\space ##5\\[8pt]}%
    \renewcommand{\glsgroupskip}{}
}

\makeglossaries

\newacronym{A}{A}{AAAAAAAAA}
\newacronym{B}{B}{BBBBBBBBB}
\glsaddall

\begin{document}
\printglossary[style=mylong, title=List of Abbreviations]
\end{document}
```

Compiling gives me the following warning:

> Package glossaries Warning: Deprecated command \glossarystyle.  I recommend you switch to
>   \setglossarystyle unless you want to maintain backward compatibility
>   on input line 21.

How can I get rid of this warning?

Comment: Is there a problem with using `\setglossarystyle` as the warning message states?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Using `\setglossarystyle{mylong}` instead of `[style=mylong]` does not help. I still get the warning.

Comment: @Shery You have to use `\setglossarystyle{long}` instead of `\glossarystyle{long}` in the definition of `\newglossarystyle{mylong}`

Comment: @karlkoeller if I use `\setglossarystyle{long}` in the definition the gap between the acronyms `[8pt]` is not produced.

Answer (score 2):

You can disable the warning using package `silence`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[toc, nonumberlist,nopostdot]{glossaries}
\usepackage{silence}
\WarningFilter{glossaries}{Deprecated command}% Removes warning starting with "Deprecated command"

\setlength{\glsdescwidth}{0.8\linewidth}

\newglossarystyle{mylong}{
\glossarystyle{long}
    \renewcommand*{\glossaryentryfield}[5]{%
        \glsentryitem{##1}\glstarget{##1}{##2} & ##3\glspostdescription\space ##5\\[8pt]}%
        \renewcommand{\glsgroupskip}{}
}

\makeglossaries

\newacronym{A}{A}{AAAAAAAAA}
\newacronym{B}{B}{BBBBBBBBB}
\glsaddall

\begin{document}
\printglossary[style=mylong, title=List of Abbreviations]
\end{document}
```